# Ng-repeat not updating on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to allow the user to hide and show a div inside an ng-repeat. From the console, I can see that the object is indeed changing to true but the ng-show/ng-hide part isn't working as expected. I tried the $apply method but it keeps returning an 'already running' error.

Markup

```
<div ng-repeat="q in questions">
    <div ng-show="q.active">
        ....
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="q.active">
        ....
    </div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="set_active($index)">Activate</a>
</div>
```

Ctrl file

```
 $scope.questions = [{content: '..', active: true}, {content: '...', active: false}];
 $scope.set_active = function($index){
     $scope.questions[$index].active = true;
 }
```

Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You missed a `$`before scope.set_active.

Comment: beware that `$index` is only index of unfiltered items in collection, not the whole collection if any filtering is being used. Best practice is not to use it unless 100% sure nothing will be filtering data. Better would be `set_active(q)` and use `indexOf()` to determine it's absolute index in controller

Comment: @L105 thanks that was just a typo here. I didn't copy the code.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: The code is working. See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bP4ZGTBsscZ3vw0kOOsM?p=preview But what do you mean with ng-show/ng-hide part isn't working as expected? charlietfl is right don't pass an $index to set_active. Simply pass the question object and modify it. (See the above plunker)

Comment: Thanks @bekite the code is working but even when I copy the exact same code back in my project, it's still not working as expected. I used yeoman to create the project. Do you think this could be affecting anything?

Comment: Yeoman can't be the problem. Try to update the plunker to match as closely as possible to your code. So we can help you further.